# Setting up Dante on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: server, socks5

I'm trying to set up and configure socks5 server that requires authentication.

I've got dante to run on ubuntu and set up configuration to be able to connect without authentication first:

```
internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0
method: username none
user.privileged: root
client pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
protocol:  tcp udp
}
```

after this I've started dante by

```
/etc/init.d/danted start
```

`netstat -n -a` shows:

```
tcp        0      0 10.135.9.111:1080       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

However, I can't connect to it from the outside.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Open the port in the firewall (if you haven't done so already). There is a firewall GUI that you can use to make the necessary changes.

Comment: @user233005 I've edited this to make more clear that it really is an answer. But I recommend that you edit it further to explain exactly what you're recommending. What firewall GUI are you recommending? How should it be used in this case? You can explain this by clicking the *edit* link below your answer and adding the information to your answer.